# extension of coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

suppose we have an exact sequence of locally free sheaves on a smooth variety:
$$
0\rightarrow E \rightarrow F \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} G \rightarrow 0.
$$
On an open subset $U\subset X$, this splits.
Suppose $H$ is a proper subsheaf of $G$. Then on $U$, regard $H$ as a subsheaf of $F$. take its coherent extension $H'\subset f^{-1}(H) $ on $X$. It is torsion free.
Then the kernel of $H'\rightarrow H$ on $X$ is subsheaf of $E$ and supported on $X-U$. hence the kernel is zero since $E$ is locally free.

Assume that $H$ is reflexive. Is it correct that 
 the cokernel of $H'\rightarrow H$ is supported in codimension two subset (it is a torsion sheaf). ?

(take double dual and use that $H'\subset H'^{**}$ is isomorphism outside codim two subset)

Answer (score 3):

No that is not true.  Already there are counterexamples on $X=\mathbb{P}^1$.  Consider the standard short exact sequence, $$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}(-1) \to \mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(+1) \to 0,$$ and take $H=G=\mathcal{O}(+1)$.  Every torsion-free, coherent subsheaf $H'$ of $\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}$ is automatically locally free.  So your sheaf $H'$ is an invertible sheaf that admits an injective sheaf homomorphism to $\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}$.  By taking the transpose map, $(H')^\vee$ has nonzero global sections.  Thus $(H')^\vee$ has nonnegative degree, i.e., $H'$ has nonpositive degree.  Thus the induced morphism $H'\to H$ fails to be an isomorphism already in codimension $1$.